# Why my browser is not respecting the Validation groups in my class

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a user class with some constraints.
To build and update the user class objects i use a form type called UserType.

In order to make a specific task i am trying to test the validations groups (constraints).
What i understood from the symfony doc is that whenever you add a new group to your constraints, they will never apply unless you specify it namely.
Because the 'Default' constraints will apply in first place.

So i have added a validation group to one of my class properties, which should initially be a required field.
But when i try to validate the form the browser told me that the field is required.

What should i add to my code to tell the browser that this field is required only if this validation group is requested.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Ajouter une image", groups={"mandatory"})
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     minWidth = 200,
 *     maxWidth = 1000,
 *     minHeight = 200,
 *     maxHeight = 1000,
 *     groups={"mandatory"}
 * )
 */

private $cover;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation constraints are not about client side, but about server side.

If you want to set a field as required (or not) for browser html5 validation you have to specify it in your form builder :

```
$builder->add('cover', null, [
    'required' => false,
]);
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required)